# Memory Leakage in SQLite3

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sqlite

We have found a memory leak in the following function. If we put a correct message as parameter of the function, the SQL query is executed properly, and the memory stays constant. But if the message has characters as `'`, then (obviously) fails to execute, but the memory starts increasing.

```
int syslog_hwmod(unsigned short int type, unsigned short int err, const char *msg, const char *agent)
{
    //Local variables:
    int             aux;        //Auxiliary variable to check the returned errors of the functions.
    unsigned int     t0;        //Current linux time in seconds. 
    char             buffer[BUFFER_SIZE_LOG];    //Variable to write the SQL statement. 
    char             *errMsg = 0;    //Error message returned in the executing SQL statements.
    sqlite3         *db;             //Sqlite3 object that refers to the database connection.

    //Initializing variables:
    t0 = (unsigned int) time(NULL);        //Save the current linux time in seconds.

    //Open the syslog database connection:
    aux = sqlite3_open(DB_PATH_SYSLOG, &db);
    if(aux != SQLITE_OK)        //Check the errors in the database connection.
        return EGP0;

    //Creates the SQL statement and executes it:
    sprintf (buffer, "INSERT INTO syslog_hwmod VALUES (NULL,'%u','%hu','%hu','%s','%s');", t0, 
                                                                              type, err, msg, agent);
    do{
        aux = sqlite3_exec(db, buffer, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);

        sqlite3_free(errMsg);

    }while((aux == SQLITE_BUSY) || (aux == SQLITE_LOCKED));     //If the database is locked or busy, 
                                                                //need to try again.

    if(aux != SQLITE_OK)        //Check the errors in the execution. 
        return EGP1;

    //Close the syslog database connection:
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return NOERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error happens, that function aborts execution before `sqlite3_close` is called.

Whan you have allocated resources (like the opened database), you must ensure that these resources are always freed:

```
aux = sqlite3_open(DB_PATH_SYSLOG, &db);
if (aux != SQLITE_OK)
    return EGP0;

...

sqlite3_close(db);

return aux != SQLITE_OK ? EGP1 : NOERROR;
```

---

Please note that it is possible to format SQL strings correctly with [sqlite3_mprintf](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).